# Added element doesn't show in RecyclerView after deleting another with swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Edit: if anyone is having the same problem in the future it was a pretty easy fix. I used clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) to handle when the entire drag was finished and had forgotten to call it's super-method. That's why it didn't update properly.

Original question:

Here's the entire code: https://github.com/vustav/Ppaaiinntt/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/decent/rvtest

Everything works fine except when I add an element right after deleting another. It does exist though. If I add another there's a properly sized space between the old list and the new element. I use a string where they add their names before a print and it shows there, and if I drag to change positions of the elements it shows up properly.

My reputation doesn't allow me to post images so an imgur-album will have to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufkxi.jpg

- On the first image there's three elements and the string is printed at the bottom.
- The second image is after the swipe. Notice the string is updated.
- The third is after adding another "111". The string is correct but it doesn't show up in the view.
- The fourth is after adding another. The string is still correct and the new element shows up in the view.
- The last image is after dragging to change the position of the last two elements. Now everything is fine again.

These are the relevant methods (I think):

```
protected void add(PictureElement pe){
    chain.add(pe);
    notifyItemInserted(chain.size()-1);
}

public void remove(int position) {
    chain.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

protected void swap(int from, int to){
    chain.swap(from, to);
    notifyItemMoved(from, to);
}
```

Edit: onBindViewHolder, getItemCount and the ViewHolder:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chain.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PEViewHolder PEViewHolder, int i) {
    PictureElement pe = chain.get(i);
    PEViewHolder.name.setText(pe.getName());
}

protected static class PEViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView name;

    public PEViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your Adapter code, specifically bind method and getCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting quote on the different notify methods you are using

> **public final void notifyItemRemoved (int position)** Notify any registered observers that the item previously located at position has
>   been removed from the data set. The items previously located at and
>   after position may now be found at oldPosition - 1. This is a
>   structural change event. Representations of other existing items in
>   the data set are still considered up to date and will not be rebound,
>   though their positions may be altered. Parameters position : Position
>   of the item that has now been removed.
>
> **public final void notifyItemRangeChanged (int positionStart, int itemCount)** Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items
>   starting at position positionStart have changed. Equivalent to calling
>   notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemCount, null);. This is an item
>   change event, not a structural change event. It indicates that any
>   reflection of the data in the given position range is out of date and
>   should be updated. The items in the given range retain the same
>   identity.

Could you try and comment this block of code and check if it works

```
//Called by the ItemTouchHelper when the user interaction with an element is over and it also
    // completed its animation
    /*
@Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

        //update from where the action took place
        mPEAdapter.updateChain(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());

        //clearView is called after onMove so any drags or swipes are complete
        dragging = false;
        mPEAdapter.setSwipe(false);
    }
*/
```

Comment: @GrandDuc too bad.. without your full code it's impossible to do a debug. Are you by any chance using a custom LayoutManager?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Added a link to the code in the original question.

Comment: @GrandDuc try the updated answer, it's pretty easy just comment that block of code, the **clearView()** override inside the 'PETouchHelper'

Comment: It does work without clearView()! But that raises another problem. I need the chain to update from the start of a drag, 3-7 has to update from 3, and so on. onMove() gets updated at every swap, so 3-4, 4-5, 5-6 and 6-7. Do you know how I can register where a drag starts and only update once it's completed?

Comment: By update I mean update the list of objects (strings right now but it won't be in the final application), and not the swap-animations.

Comment: @GrandDuc alright, just correct me if I'm wrong, you are describing a "structural update" of the dataset: "There are two different classes of data change events, item changes and structural changes. Item changes are when a single item has its data updated but no positional changes have occurred. **Structural changes** are when items are inserted, removed or **moved** within the data set."  
Just to make sure, you are talking about dragging and moving an item, am I understanding correctly?

ps. thanks for accepting the answer

Comment: I think I'm only interested in structural updates. The items will be images and effects and the recyclerview represents the order in which they should be applied. Every image and effect will have the state of the final image (the one displayed in the imageview) at that point in the chain stored in a bitmap, so when one is moved there is no need to update the entire chain, just from the first item that is effected by the change. Hmm, this was harder to describe than I thaught... Hope you get an idea.